# Ansible: create a list by extracting several attributes from another list

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

I have a list like this:

first list:

```
volumes:
      - {device_name: '/dev/sda1', volume_type: 'gp2', volume_size: '80', delete_on_termination: true ,os_device_name: '/dev/xvda', mount_path: '/'}
      - {device_name: '/dev/xvdb', volume_type: 'standard', volume_size: '500', delete_on_termination: true, os_device_name: '/dev/xvdb', mount_path: '/data' }
```

and I want to create a new list with the attributes:

```
device_name,volume_type,volume_size,delete_on_termination
```

to be look like this in one line:

second list:

```
volumes:
      - {device_name: /dev/sda1, volume_type: 'gp2', volume_size: '80', delete_on_termination: true}
      - {device_name: '/dev/xvdb', volume_type: 'standard', volume_size: '500', delete_on_termination: true}
```

**why?**

I need to create an ec2 instance with the ec2 module with several volumes in the same volumes paramer

```
- name: Create new ec2 instance
  ec2:
    ....
    volumes: "{{volumes}}"
    ....
```

FYI: the **second** list is working as expected but I can't find a way to extract the only specific attributes that I need **from** the first list

any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a dict like this:
>
> ```
> volumes:
>       - ...
>       - ...
> ```

This is not a dictionary, but a list.

---

And this is the solution:

```
- set_fact:
    volumes: "{{ volumes | json_query(jsonquery) }}"
  vars:
    jsonquery: "[].{device_name: device_name, volume_type: volume_type, volume_size: volume_size, delete_on_termination: delete_on_termination}"
```

Comment: works like a charm. I will rename the question to list instead of dict. there is any way to do this without set_fact ? I mean inside the volumes parameter?. for example: "{{ volumes | json_query([].{device_name: device_name, volume_type: volume_type, volume_size: volume_size, delete_on_termination: delete_on_termination}) }}" - this is not working

Comment: Of course there is, but **you** asked for replacing `volumes` with `volumes` (quoting your question "first list: `volumes`, second list `volumes`").　・　Regarding what you posted in comment - quote the query.

Comment: I just described how this list should be look alike to be more understandable . I can use the set_face but the code can be more nicer if it will be inside the volume parameter . it will be nice of you if you will expand your answer and add a way to do this inside the volume parameter :)

Comment: Copy-paste everything except for `set_fact`. Done.